# How to get Sum of all doc_counts from term aggregation query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have reviews and each review is linked to a property. So for a property id there could be multiple reviews and these reviews can be duplicate also.
Now I need to get the total of duplicate reviews for each property.

This is how I can get duplicate reviews for each property

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "reviewKeyword": {
              "value": ""
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "propertyGrouping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "propertyId",
        "size": 10
      }
      , "aggs": {
        "dupReviwes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "reviewKeyword",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now what I also want is the sum of the doc counts returned by the sub aggregation.
This is the sample response

```
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": 532,
      "doc_count": 2431,
      "dupReviwes": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 10,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 2382,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Good hotel",
            "doc_count": 31
          },
          {
            "key": "Overall good",
            "doc_count": 18
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": 496,
      "doc_count": 2207,
      "dupReviwes": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 8,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 2185,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Good",
            "doc_count": 16
          },
          {
            "key": "Nice",
            "doc_count": 6
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So I also want the sum of doc counts per bucket
so for the above case: for the two keys

```
Key : 532
sum_doc_count=49 (31+18)

key : 496
sum_doc_count=32 (16 + 6)
```

is this possible with some queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that easily using a [`sum_bucket` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html), simply modify your query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "reviewKeyword": {
              "value": ""
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "propertyGrouping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "propertyId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dupReviews": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "reviewKeyword",
            "size": 100
          }
        },
        "sum_buckets": {
          "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "dupReviews>_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this but was just missing the correct bucket path "_count" in that, this is what i was looking for

Comment: hello sir @Val, the "dupReviews>_count" does not work in the **sum_bucket** aggregation, it's missing from the elacsitcsearch's response :( any alternatives for this?